# Check if MSSQL data were motified/updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a MSSQL db with a table, which these attributes:
`id`
`name`
`status`
`timestamp`

Every minute my .NET Application checks if a server is available and adds data to the table.
Server is available -> `status == 1`
Server is unavailable -> `status == 0`

I wanted to know if there is a possibilty to check if someone **manually changed/updated data**(like `UPDATE {TABLE} set status = 1 WHERE timestamp...`?

I just want to know if someone(cause I'm not the only one, who takes care of this script and db) set status to 1 altough the status was to 0, that means the server wasn't available.

Comment: Is it one row per server or multiple rows per server? I.e. does the application actually *adds* (inserts) new statuses or *changes* (updates) an existing row's value? Can the other people's privileges be limited with respect to that particular table?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column to get user or login name  and update on every .net execution.

Comment: Create a login and user for your .net application and  define default value for user column that is USER.